# stringbuilder characters find

Tags: scala, character, stack-overflow, stringbuilder

```
  def ff(c: Char): Boolean =  
  {
    while (cursor <= end)
    {
      if (buffer.charAt(cursor) == c)
      {
      return true
      }
      else
      {
      cursor += 1
      }
    }
    return false   
  }
  def ff(p: Char => Boolean): Boolean = 
  {
    ff(p)
  }
```

Idea of the function is to start at the cursor and find the next occurrence of a character defined by a variable called c taken as a parameter to the function, doing it this way results in a stackoverflow when tested with Junit could somebody explain where I'm going wrong?

Note(The cursor needs to stay at the position where the char is found)

I've also included the predicate version of the FF function where (p) is a predicate to search by I'm unsure which of these is causing the overflow.

Comment: Your predicate version calls itself and it caused SOE.

Comment: Any ideas how to get the predicate version to work? I can't compare p to the char at cursor with a Boolean expression as it will almost always result in false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...could somebody explain where I'm going wrong?

One thing you're doing wrong is using the Scala language to write C code. One of the goals/purposes/joys of learning a new language is that it can teach you a new way to approach problem solving. Taking the time to learn the idioms and best practices of a particular language is one way to get there.

Some other things that aren't right:

- `import scala.io.StdIn` - is unused
- `buffer.charAt(cursor)` - This will throw if `cursor`== `end`, which the `while` condition allows.
- `def ff(p: Char => Boolean)` - This does nothing but call itself. A guaranteed StackOverflow.

See if this gets you closer to what you want.

```
def ff(c: Char): Boolean = {
  val next = buffer.indexOf(c, cursor)
  cursor = if (next < 0) end else next
  cursor == next
}
def ff(p: Char => Boolean): Boolean =
  cursor != end && (p(buffer(cursor)) || {
    cursor += 1
    ff(p)
  })
```

Comment: PERFECT! thankyou so much, last issue is that I need to be able to do this with the cursor going in the opposite direction as well and indexOf doesn't work backwards I don't think? would lastIndexOf work?

Comment: Have a look at: `lastIndexOf(c, cursor)`

Comment: `def fb(c: Char): Boolean = 
  {
    val prev = buffer.lastIndexOf(c, cursor)
    cursor = if (prev < 0) 0 else prev
    cursor == prev
     
  }
  
  def fb(p: Char => Boolean): Boolean = 
  {
    cursor != 0 && (p(buffer(cursor)) || 
    {
    cursor -= 1
    ff(p)
    }
    )
  }`

doesn't work :/

Comment: I see two problems: 1) there's a reference to `ff(p)` where you actually want `fb(p)`, and 2) `0` means "at-the-beginning", not "out-of-bounds" the way `end` does. So you can't `fb(p)` to the 1st `Char` and return `true`. For that you'd have to allow the cursor to go to `-1` or code a slightly more complicated `cursor == 0` block.